# What should an iOS JSON payload submitting to an API look like?

Tags: ios, json, api, payload

We have an iOS application that grabs model data from an API. The user of the iOS device performs actions that link up the model data and creates relationships between them. The iOS then submits back to the API to save the relationship and allow for the relationship to be viewable in the web application.

The JSON payload has the potentially of being large if all the objects that were associated with the new relationship are submitted with their attributes.

```
"peoples_vehicles": [
     {
         "owner" : {
             "id" : 8282, <----------this would be a UUID
             "name" : "John Smith",  
             "address": "123 Fake Street",    
         }, 
         "vehicles" : [
             {
                 "id" : 1234,  <----------this would be a UUID
                 "name" : "FORD F150",
                 "make" : "F150",
                 "model" : "FORD",
                 "year" : "2017",
             },
             {
                 "id" : 5678,   <----------this would be a UUID
                 "name" : "FORD ESCAPE",
                 "make" : "ESCAPE",
                 "model" : "FORD",
                 "year" : "2013",
             }
         ]
    },
    {
       ... another person with their vehicles
    }
]
```

Since the data being sent back is all data that was originally from the API, should the iOS application even bother sending all the attributes back? Should the iOS application simply send back all the relationships with only the objects ids? We use UUIDs

```
"peoples_vehicles": [
     {
         "owner" : {
             "id" : 8282, <----------this would be a UUID
         }, 
         "vehicles" : [
             {
                 "id" : 1234,  <----------this would be a UUID
             },
             {
                 "id" : 5678,   <----------this would be a UUID
             }
         ]
    },
    {
       ... another person with their vehicles
    }
]
```

We seem to be leaning more towards just sending ID for pre-existing data. It makes the submit payload from iOS to API have very few attributes that are actually strings (none in this example).

There are cases when we would have to create new custom objects. In that case, all the attributes would be sent over and the ID of this new object would be null to indicate that this object has to be created.

```
"peoples_vehicles": [
     {
         "owner" : {
             "id" : 8282, <----this would be a pre-existing object
         }, 
         "vehicles" : [
             {
                 "id" : 1234,  <----this would be a pre-existing object
             },
             {
                 "id": null <----new object that needs to be saved
                 "name" : "FORD F150",
                 "make" : "F150",
                 "model" : "FORD",
                 "year" : "2017",
             }
         ]
    },
    {
       ... another person with their vehicles
    }
]
```

Would this be a decent approach? Looking at Stripe and Shopify API as examples, this seems to work nicely, but I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything and if I should be included the attributes for objects that are pre-existing.

Comment: FYI - nothing about this is specific to iOS. It's a question that could applied for any OS.

Comment: Sure but for my use case we are using iOS which is why I reference it. Perhaps there is a different preferred convention when submitting a JSON payload from iOS. Do you have an opinion or answer for this question? @rmaddy